# formで囲ったラジオボタンから選択された値を取り出したい

Tags: javascript, html, html5

本来フォームに囲まれた中なら下記のコードでチェックされた値を取得出来るのですが、おそらくnav, Ul, li 等を使用しているので上手く取得出来ないのでしょうか？

```js
let DOM = {}
DOM.languageInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.language input[name="country"]')

console.log(DOM.languageInputs.value);
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false" autocomplete="off">
 <div class="song__language">
     <nav class="language">
         <ul>
             <li>
       <input type="radio" id="EN" name="country" value="1" checked="checked">
       <label for="EN">English</label>
     </li>
                <li>
        <input type="radio" id="JPN" name="country" value="2">
        <label for="JPN">日本語</label>
       </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: 「本来フォームに囲まれた中なら下記のコードでチェックされた値を取得出来る」とありますが、それを実現できるコードは書けますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()`で返るのは配列のようなオブジェクトで、`value`というプロパティはありません。

`querySelector*()`がお好きなら、

```js
DOM.languageInputs = document.querySelector('.language input[name="country"]:checked');`
```

と変えれば `DOM.languageInputs.value` で目的の値が得られます。

囲っている`<form>`が変数`form1`に入っているとすると、`form1.country.value` でも同様の結果が得られます。

Comment: 上手くいきました。ありがとうございます。質問してよかったです。